# CSS navbar with border-radius and background image

Tags: html, css, background-image, navbar

Hello guys. I'm trying to implement some features to my navbar on learning purposes. I had an idea to make but have got no idea on how to put it into practice.

My HTML tree:

**main**

--- header > div > h1 and p

--- nav > div > a*4

I set a `background-image` to the tag 'main' to cover it entirely.

[image: how it looks]

I would like to make the image fit ONLY my tags 'a'.

[image: Something like this]

But instead of setting the links to a red background color (like the image above), I want the 'main' background image to fit in.

Comment: Please post your html and css code required to reproduce your situation

Comment: please share html and css

Answer (score -1):

```
a {
  background-image: url(var(--main));
  background-size: cover;
}
```